# How to integrate right-to-left (Persian) in a left-to-right line (English)?

Tags: polyglossia, alignment, right-to-left, persian

I am writing a paper in English that has some Persian in it. To do that I am using `\usepackage{polyglossia}`. The problem is that the Persian script appears left-to-right like the main English sentence, and not right-to-left.
When I write in Persian on a separate line, it's aligned correctly (right-to-left).

here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{latex}{Command \InputIfFileExists}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{hologo}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{persian}
% Main serif font for English (Latin alphabet) text
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
% define fonts for other languages
\newfontfamily\persianfont{Scheherazade}[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.8]

\title{ Multilingual Text using Polyglossia}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

This is a mainly English document that contains other languages. Here is some Persian text: \begin{persian}
من کبک دوست دارم
\end{persian}

How I want it to look but in the same line:

\begin{persian}
من کبک دوست دارم
\end{persian}

\end{document}
```

P.S 1
Spent hours looking for an answer, tried using Persian with babel and the XePersian package but with no luck. Please help, any advice would be greatly appreciated!

P.S 2
Maybe it is a font issue?

Comment: Does `\textpersian` work? You can auto-detect languages with `babel`.

Comment: OMG `\textpersian` worked!, I feel stupid! Thank you very much!!!!
How does auto-detect languages with `babel` work?

Comment: You would add a line like `\babelprovide[import=fa, onchar=fonts ids]{persian}` and then declare a `\babelfont[persian]{rm}`. This doesn’t work perfectly, but should be able to display short passages of Persian as part of a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the answer here from the comment: Use

```
\textpersian{من کبک دوست دارم}
```

Another option is to use the `babel` command

```
\babelprovide[import=fa, onchar=fonts ids]{persian}
```

This automatically detects the script you type in and changes languages accordingly. It’s not absolutely perfect, but it can handle short phrases from a second language in the middle of a line.